# Why removing WebMvcTest annotation from my test in SpringBoot application causes ComponentScan to fail?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a test defined with:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { ... })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
@WebMvcTest(secure = false)
public class MyTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests  {

     @Autowired SomeClass target;

     @Test public void test() { Assert.assertTrue(target != null); } // MCVE

}
```

Here's my ContextConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

}
```

This test works fine, but it wastes a lot of time in MVC initialization due to the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. This particular test does not require any MVC functionality. The annotation ended up in there as a result of trial-and-error, to get the `@Autowired` annotation to work correctly. But now I want to remove it.

So... I went ahead and removed the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. But then the test fails because apparently the `@ComponentScan` does not have any effect unless `@WebMvcTest` is present (which I now remember, is the reason I added it).

Here's the actual error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '...' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I tried adding `@SpringBootTest` but it made no difference.

If instead, I add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, I get a different error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

What annotation am I missing?

Comment: You might want to add the rest of the test, or some information on what its doing. That setup looks rather odd.

Comment: What's the spring boot versions, what is `contextconfiguration` loading, what is being component scanned? Is there a stack trace associated with loading this? 

Also what is on your main `application`? as `webmvctest` is a slice test it will load _anything_ that is defined on the main boot application too  e.g. if you happened to define any `Bean` or `@Enable` on the `SpringBootApplication` class they will also be loaded but its doubtful that is the issue as you have tried SpringBootTest

Comment: SpringBoot is 2.0.5.RELEASE. ContextConfiguration is loading a JdbcTemplate. What is being component-scanned is the package where SomeClass lives. And why should it matter what's in the main application? I'm trying to setup a simple unit test of SomeClass ONLY.

Comment: I'll add the contextconfiguration class

Comment: Look here: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#spring-boot-1-4-simplifications

Comment: @RandyCasburn your link tells me to use #SpringBootTest, but as I mentioned in the question, I already tried that and it made no difference. Changing the RunWith to SpringRunner also makes no difference. And removing all the other annotations also makes no difference. No difference meaning, I get the same error with or without the prospective change.

Comment: OK...that's really odd. Would have to know more about your name-spacing and file/folder structure.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the structure is fairly straightfoward, I have controller/dao/service packages, plus a dedicated "boot" package where I put the SpringBootApplication class. The test above lives in the service package.

Comment: Is it possible to decompose WebMvcTest into more specific annotations, which can be tried individually?

Comment: Yes, they are listed here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html

Comment: That's just the standard javadoc. I have that in my IDE. It didn't really make sense to try any of those (just based on their names, I don't think they're applicable).

Comment: Your package structure is suspect to me. Why? Because the SpringBoot application class has be in a hierarchy and at the top level of that hierarchy for all other classes in the app. To overcome that configuration, you can annotate the application to say "my components/configs/etc are in this folder structure over here". Sounds to me like your configurations are different for runtime vs. test. Is it possible you have an annotation on your application class that is not on your test class in this regard?

Comment: references: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html. and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, EnableAutoConfiguration. And yes I did move the app class out of the top-level package into a 'boot' subpackage, to overcome some other issue. I don't want to get sidetracked now. There must be a simple annotation to tell SpringTest to componentscan my classes.

Comment: First line in the linked doc is, "Spring Boot does not require any specific code layout to work" :-)

Comment: OK..just trying to help. I'm out then.

Comment: As long as you configure it properly...which you clearly have not in your test environment.  Anyway...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

> ***Why removing WebMvcTest annotation from my test in SpringBoot application causes ComponentScan to fail?***

Because you have not annotated the class in a way that Spring's IoC/Dependency injection can work correctly.

Now that the answer is clear, here are a couple of suggestions for you to try. They **may or may not work** depending upon how your project and dependencies etc are put together.

END EDIT:

> This particular test does not require any MVC functionality.

You should consider using one of the more direct [auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests) annotations for the your tests if you don't need all of MVC but do want auto configuration. For instance, it appears you are testing with some data system. Perhaps the [@DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) or [@JdbcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jdbc-test) annotations would provide a more streamlined approach. These will enable auto configuration (IoC and Dependency injection).

> ***What annotation am I missing?***

As written above, the annotation you are missing is `@Configuration`

This is counter intuitive here because this isn't a configuration class. But without an appropriate annotation that enables Dependency injection to occur, this is the only way to get this to work. Why?

From the docs:

> public @interface ComponentScan
>
> ```
>   Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration classes.
> ```

So your choices are:

1. Use a different auto config annotation as suggested above
2. Add the `@Configuration` annotation

Comment: #JdbcTest gives me "Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests.". #Configuration gives the original error indicating a componentscan didn't work.

Comment: @AlexR - You're very welcome for the answer, I'm glad to take all this time helping you. I've edited the answer a bit to clarify that the answer is clearly provided. I have no idea what your project looks like. If you want to make the project available on GitHub or something, I'll take a look at it and fix it for you. But I can't guess about what you have lurking in the dark :-).

Comment: thank you for your efforts. At this point I think it's best to wait and see if there are any other ideas. Perhaps someone who has experienced the exact same problem can just effortlessly recall the solution. I have tried every combination that you suggested, nothing works.